# How to align list indent correctly with floating div in the left?

Tags: css

I can not figure out a way to solve the problem of list indentation when there is a floating div in the left of the list. I want to use 'list-style-position:outside' but this out side indent overlapped with the left div, if use 'list-style-position:inside' the text alignment from second line will not go with the first line. The following are my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>List Problem</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style></head>
<body>
<div style="width:400px">
<div style="float:left; width:200px; height:40px; background-color:red;">
</div>
<div style="margin-left:20px">
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two separated into two lines</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
<li>Five</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I can not upload image but if you view the above code from a browser you can know my meanings. I want to make the list dot not been covered by the red box, and the item Three, Four and Five align as they are aligned now. Also the multi-line of one < li> element should have the same left start position. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hi nemozhp you mean list in the red background right?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>List Problem</title>
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="">
    <div style="width: 200px; background-color: red;">

    <ul style="padding: 0pt; margin: 0pt; list-style: none outside none;">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two separated into two lines</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    </ul>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi,No, I mean, list should out side the red background, but also the dot(list-style-type) of the list.